# Where to find built Angular files

Tags: angular

Where do I find built files of Angular? The only way I know is to comb through the Angular repositories and download each library that I need. I would rather not use node_modules or require as I don't understand this method very well.

I don't want to use the QuickStart because I want to do a project that has as few files as possible.

Comment: Well, you could download the raw files from [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/). But it not a good idea, you really, really should use a package manager(like `npm`/`bower`, which is that `node_modules` directory you are talking about). Why do you want to make it more difficult on yourself? If you don't understand them, you should try to learn.

Comment: That's the problem. Where do I learn? The only thing I can find is the QuickStart tutorials, which do not address SystemJS or the module loader at all. And I thought I remember seeing something about using webpack. Where do I find this info? It's not on the angular website that I can tell.

Comment: That's a fair point, and unfortunately I'm not really familiar enough with Angular(I only work with old `AngularJS`) to recommend a good tutorial to you, sorry. Apologies, hopefully someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for wanting to start a new project without having to know the ins and outs of SystemJS or Webpack, look at the Angular-CLI.  [Here is a neat article that shows how much simpler the CLI makes it to get started building an Angular application.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-angular-cli-for-faster-angular-2-projects)

Although, the CLI won't teach you all the intricacies of Angular, it takes all the 'setup' work out of the equation.  It let's you create a new project with a simple command and be able to build it with a single command. [Here is another website that takes a different approach to teaching some of the concepts in Angular2+.](http://learnangular2.com/)

These next two sites are curated lists of resources for learning Angular:

- http://www.angular2.com/
- https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS2-Learning

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.